# How to keep resources in proguard_rules.pro?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

How can i keep resources in activity only and method names and variables be obfuscated?

For example i want to keep R.layout.activity_main.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the auto-generated layout constants you can use the following rule:

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$layout {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

This will keep *all* layout constants, if you want to keep only a specific one, adjust the rule as needed.